# Perl system(command) then kill command

Tags: windows, perl, netstat

I'm trying to output a system `netstat -an -p TCP $interval > $log` for a sleep of $seconds, and then quit/kill the netstat command but am having trouble getting it to work correctly.

If I use `start netstat...`, my sleep and kill commands work, but it does not write to the log.

If I only use `netstat...`, then it writes to the logs, but will not move on to the sleep and kill commands.

Any ideas on how to solve this??

```
$netstat_cmd = "netstat -an -p TCP $interval >$netstatlog;
$stop_netstat_cmd = "c:\utilities\pskill NETSTAT.exe";
system($netstat_cmd);
sleep $seconds;
system "$stop_netstat_cmd";
```

Thanks!

Comment: It'd be easier to make suggestions if we could see the source code. Also, `start` smells a lot like Windows, which might influence the answers. If this is on Windows system, please add [tag:windows] to the tags on the question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is for windows..will add code a little later, this typing not working so well from mobile device.

Comment: Don't try to get your source into the comments; it just won't work well. Instead, use the [edit] link under your question to add the source there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`IPC::Run`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun)? It has a `kill_kill()` method that is portable across Unix and Win32 (the latter is important if you're running on Windows as your "start" seems to possibly indicate).

---

As far as your own approach, the `start xxx` redirect doesn't work, so the easiest fix is to:

- Create a batch file to run netstat and redirect to a file
- Launch the batch file with `start`

Comment: I think the batch file option is the fix for my scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is that system() runs its command and waits for it to return, so you never get as far as calling sleep().  You need to run netstat from another process, or in the background.  You can use fork() to acheive this, by spawning another process from your main process, and having that run netstat:

```
my $interval = 5;
my $netstatlog = "foo.tmp";
my $seconds = 10;

my $netstat_cmd = "netstat -an -p TCP $interval >$netstatlog";
my $stop_netstat_cmd = "pskill NETSTAT.exe";

if (my $pid = fork()) { # make new process
    print "launched netstat $pid\n";
}
else { # this is the "new" process
    system($netstat_cmd);
    exit();
}

sleep $seconds;

system "$stop_netstat_cmd";
```

(I don't have pskill, so you'll have to make that part work by yourself...)

Comment: I don't think this would work for windows, which is what I will mainly be using it for. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote and tested it on Windows.  fork() used to be a problem, but not so much these days.

Answer (score 0):

[`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper) makes this kind of task easy for you.

```
use Forks::Super;
fork { cmd => $netstat_cmd, timeout => $seconds };
wait;
```